# How to make Xcode 8.2.1 show the line that causes an exception?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, xcode8

I have figured out the line of codes that caused an exception. However, when i ran it again for a couple times, it always highlighted the line where the main class was located but not the actual line which caused the exception.

Also indeed, i have tried a lots of solutions introduced by other developers, such as

go to Preferences > Behavior > Exits unexpectedly > choose show line...
or click the Product tab > Scheme > Edit scheme > check the "Zombie Objects" box
or simply created an exception breakpoint on the left.

Whatever i did, none of the methods above worked. So please help !!! Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3):

Open breakpoint navigator on the left side view (seventh icon), click + button on the left down corner, select exception breakpoint, choose "All" on the "Exception" option, catch on break, and run the project in debug mode.

Comment: Yes, i tried that too. It didn't work. That's one of the solutions i wrote in the description.

Comment: Did you try "On catch" break instead of "On throw"? It normally works but sometimes it's not working for various reasons. You should provide your code.